# when rendering metafile, the texts are too large

Tags: delphi

I'm having a problem with metafile rendering in my Delphi XE application.

the problem is that when I'm rendering the metafile, the texts are too large.  Irfanview and FastReports render it like this:

[image: look at the text to the left of the graph]

windows 7 Paint renders it fine:  (here's what the text should look like)

[image: windows 7 Paint renders it fine]

Any ideas what is causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: How are you creating the meta file? What about some code?

Comment: Looking more closely at this on a real computer, I recognise that sort of effect. I've seen it with output of my own program. I think that's just the nature of the way some packages rasterise a metafile. Clearly the metafile is fine because one package renders it well. The other program you should look at is Word. If you want to export for consumption by a raster graphics package then export as bitmap in PNG format preferably.

Comment: thank your for your comments.   @DavidHeffernan:  the metafile is created by the 3rd party graphing engine.

Comment: i'm using a metafile so it's a "vectored" file format intended to be nice for rendering to the report canvas for printing.

Comment: OK, but you talk about bitmaps in your question and they aren't vector, they are raster

Comment: i shouldn't have mentioned rendering to a bitmap because i don't know what they render it to.

Comment: edited to remove mention of bitmap, per comment here

Answer (score 4):

`emf` files are just a list of GDI commands. In fact, they can be "played back" very easily by the system, using standard Windows GDI command (in Delphi, a `TMetaFile` is just a wrapper around those APIs).

When *IrfanView* or *FastReport* renders the metafile content, they just use Windows GDI corresponding commands. When *Windows 7 Paint* renders the metafile content, it uses the GDI+ renderer. I even think it internally convert the `emf` file into `emf+` format, then renders it with anti-aliaising using GDI+.

So if the `emf` file renders incorrectly in *IrfanView* or *FastReport*, I suspect this is because your metafile is not well formed: the third party graphic engine you are using is producing non standard emf.  A possible issue is that the font used is missing in the target system, and GDI does not substitute the font with the same as GDI+ does.

Another possibility is that the `emf` file is maybe a *dual* format: it contains both `emf` format (which was not properly created so is not rendered correctly using GDI) and `emf+` format (which is rendered as expected using GDI+). Normally this *dual* `emf/emf+`format should not exist: even the official GDI+ library does not allow to save its metafile content in *emf+*. This is some kind of "monster" format, created by your third-party library.

I suggest the following:

- Download and check your `emf` file with [EmfExplorer](http://frazmitic.free.fr/emfexplorer/);
- Try to use GDI+ to render the metafile;
- Try to use the `emf` to `emf+` converter API.

For using GDI+, take a look at an Open Source [SynGdiPlus unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/04/02/Antialiased-drawing-from-TMetaFile): it will add GDI+ anti-aliaising to your produced bitmap. It is able to convert `emf` to `emf+`. It will use native Vista/Seven API (just like Windows 7 paint), or plain Delphi code under Windows XP.

Answer (score 2):

The cause probably is that different monitor size and screen resolution ratio. GDI has parameters `HORZRES`, `HORZSIZE`, `VERTRES`, `VERTSIZE`. In most cases `HORZRES/VERTRES`, `HORZSIZE/VERTSIZE` (resolution ratio and screen ratio) are the same and everything works well... However if they are different (I have found some examples of this happening on servers) then the pixel is assumed to be rectangular, this causes `LOGFONT.lfWidth` to be calculated "wrongly". `LOGFONT.lfWidth` determines the aspect ratio of characters and this finally causes the weird looking letters.

One solution is to change the resolution so that `HORZRES/VERTRES`, `HORZSIZE/VERTSIZE` match. The other solution is to use a printer DC to render your things. Setting the `LOGFONT.lfWidth` value explicitly may help. Also updating video driver may help.

I encountered the same problem, I had temporary drawing to a metafile canvas that used `GetDC(0)` as reference instead of printer DC. Here are some links that have the same problem:

- http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/createenhmetafile-app-running-via-remote-desktop-help-27451862.html
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/a4a12ed8-c673-4a5c-94e1-7165b16f6955

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a gamble, but:

Maybe has to do with the new system font in Vista+ that newer Delphi's support? If it happened during porting, fixate the font used in the tmetafile in the old and new version.

Comment: Without knowing the reference device context in code from OP it's just guessing.

Comment: hadn't thought of that.  i'm going to talk to the vendor.  thank you!

Comment: Martin: well, that is what "gamble" means :-)